# Whats wrong with this code? Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

I'm getting this error whenever I attempt to call -u ex. "./Randoms -u 100"

All other cases work fine. Why is it happening? How do I fix it?

I'm trying to print random numbers between lower bound -l and upper bound 
-u. All sent as command line arguments.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <time.h>

    static char *prgn;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       srand(time(NULL));
      int randomnumber;
      int nums = 10;  
      int l = 1;
      int u = 100; 
      int c = 0;
      int error = 0;
      char *options = ":n:l:u";
      prgn = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(argv[0])+1));
      strcpy(prgn,argv[0]);
      while ((c = getopt(argc,argv,options)) != -1) {
            if (c == '?') {
               c = optopt;
               printf("illegal option %c\n",c);
            } else if (c == ':') {
               c = optopt;
               printf("missing value for option %c\n",c);
            }
            else {
         switch (c) {
            case 'n':
               nums =  atoi(optarg);
               break;
            case 'u':
               u = atoi(optarg);
            break; 
            case 'l':
               l = atoi(optarg);
            break;
         }
      }
   }
       while (nums !=0){
                  randomnumber = l + rand() % (u - l);
                  printf("%d\n", randomnumber);
                  nums--;
         }
c = 0;
return 0;

}
```

Comment: What did you find when you debugged it? Where did it crash? Don't you need `u:` in the options?

Comment: Spent 4+ hours on  this to miss a goddamn colon. kms. thank you!

Comment: Sorry did not see this question was already solved.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
char *options = ":n:l:u";
```

by

```
char *options = "n:l:u:";
```